# WCF Web Service Not Working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service called "WebMethods". Below is my code.

In IWebMethods.cs:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "WebMethods")]
public interface IWebMethods
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    String Test();
}
```

in WebMethods.cs:

```
public class WebMethods : IWebMethods
{
    public String Test()
    {
        return "This is a test YEAH!!";
    }
}
```

and the calling javascript:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'WebMethods.svc/Test',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: null,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

When I execute my javascript I get the error "Internal Server Error". Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong or at least what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Could you provide more logs than 'Internal server error' ?

Comment: @fmgp, This is the only error that the service is returning. Is there someplace I can look for more detailed error messages?

Comment: Can you navigate directly to your service page?

Comment: Hi, our operation contracts are marked WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest for JavaScript. I vaguely remember some issue there, but maybe a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

What about your web.config file? Try to navigate to your service page, maybe it could give you more explanations about the error. The code above seems to be ok.